# "app does not match codfile timestamp of sibling module" exception

Tags: blackberry

My app has some png images, and when I add more images to the resource file, the compile  complains "app does not match codfile timestamp of sibling module" exception. The size of .cod file is 4.74MB. If it is more then I got the exception.

Comment: It would also help to know what the Class of the exception is, and what code was executing when it is thrown.

Comment: Hi Richard sorry for late reply, I am not able to debug the code, at starting only it is throwing the exception...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've come up against a memory limit with the sibling COD files. Your best bet would be to bundle your resources into a separate resource-only project and to include the COD files generated by that project into your JAD.

Comment: I am taking resources in src folder instead of outside the src folder in project. is it the reason for the exception?

Comment: No, it shouldn't matter what the path to the resources is.