# how-to-resolve-app-does-not-match-codfile-timestamp-of-sibling-module-exception

Tags: blackberry

["app does not match codfile timestamp of sibling module" exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145745/how-to-resolve-app-does-not-match-codfile-timestamp-of-sibling-module-exceptio)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resolve " app does not match codfile timestamp of sibling module" exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145745/how-to-resolve-app-does-not-match-codfile-timestamp-of-sibling-module-exceptio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is limit for adding resources to project.that is the error.